# How to link different contents together and display the linked content on the same page?

Tags: views, 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am fairly new to Drupal and would need some help.

on my site I have to show a few images (A - B - C - D ) created by a content type X.

Each of these images will link to a different content Type Y ( 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 ).

So when I click on A , the content 1 should show below it. Same for content B -2 , C -3, D-4.

I am not sure how to achieve such a result and what are the tools to use.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Images are just media assets on a site. By which I mean you're relating something specific in X to another thing in Y -- you could just as easily relate content titles.

You likely want to either relate things together using `Tagging` via [Taxonomies](http://drupal.org/node/1577546). Taxonomies can also have [associated images](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image) for example. Or, you want to relate content around with relationships:

- [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference)
- [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation)

Without a concrete mocked-up example with wireframes and in-depth explaination of requirements .... good luck.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I will try the taxonomy and see how it goes. My last question will be how can I show content ABCD inline and below it onclick of A B C or D, the content 1-2-3 or 4 shows up?

Comment: Taxonomies already have a built in page to show all related content when you click the taxonomy term name. You can override this output with the Views module or Dislay Suite.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use taxonomy, relation and the [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to accomplish this. Once you associate your associate your image content [A-B-C-D] with your content Type Y [1-2-3-4] then you can easily display this in a View (probably a grid style, but whatever works best for your needs). Views allows you to use a relationship between the two content types and rewrite what the [image] field links to.

Comment: Thank you Darren.I'm not sure if I am doing the right thing here. I had created a taxonomy called product and added 2 terms to id (Yellow and Green). content 1 is now in the Yellow category and content 2 is now in the Green Category. I had added a relation between content A and 1 and content B and 2. Is this the correct process? How can I edit my view now?

Comment: Let me ask a question to see if we might be able to simplify this… Why do you have these in separate content types? Do you have a lot of content in the nodes of content type Y? Because if you don't, the most simple thing to do is create an image field for this content type, display the image and just use jQuery to display the rest of the content on a click. Let me know if this solution might be better, because trying to talk through taxonomy & relations without a visual can be a challenge.

Comment: Basically all contents in X are product images. Content in Y are a gallery of images. So when I click on A which is an image thumbnail, the image gallery 1 should appear below it. I am trying not to involved coding as some authenticated user should be able to go to the admin site and be able to change the images in content 1-2-3-4 without touching any codes.